# ios - How to use MFMailComposeViewController in a "while" loop

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, while-loop

I need to use MFMailComposeViewController to send email in a "while" loop. The loop is based on an array.
I have tried to do something similar to the standard usage of this class, but I see the modal view only for the first element of the array. So only the first email is sent.

Do you have an idea of how to do this?

```
while (x = [enumerator nextObject]) {
   MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
   picker.mailComposeeDelegate = self;
   [...] // set properties of the email

   [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
   [picker: release];
}
```

Comment: whats in the while loop? are you sending same email to many people?

Comment: You need to wait somehow for the first email to be handled before displaying the next modal view.  And, of course, since "waiting" is immoral if not illegal, you need to ditch the explicit `while` loop and instead keep re-executing the same routine each time the modal view's delegate is told the previous email is done.

Comment: (You realize you can specify more than one email address on a single email, right?)

Comment: No, it is not the same email... and yes, I know that i can have multiple recipients in a single email... this is not my question.

Answer (score 0):

DO some code after the mail is sent successfully;

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller 
          didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
    [controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

   //call some code here or call some method

}
```

Comment: Actually I already now that I have to put some code in the delegate method, thank you, but my question is what should I put. I think we are talking about an asynchronous loop and my problem is that I do not know how we do this.

Comment: Do you have an idea of how to write "some code" to go back in the while loop?